# java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected

Tags: java, android, google-plus-signin

I'm making this app where I need to verify the user's email with google login.

I am getting the `java.lang.IllegalStateException` when getting the account name in the `onConnected` method!

It only happens after choosing the account to use. When it happens, account gets saved but not cleared because of the error so next time it doesn't need to ask which account to use and it works again. Both `client.isConnected()` and `client.isConnecting` return false when the error occurs.
This doesn't make sense to me because the `GoogleApiClient` should always be connected in the `onConnected` method. My code:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
    //connected to Google plus
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");
    mShouldResolve = false;

    //get email
    //error happens during the getAccountName() call
    prefs.edit().putString("email", Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(googleClient)).apply();

    //user needs to select account next time too: for debug purposes
    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(googleClient);
    //we just needed the email
    googleClient.disconnect();

    view.findViewById(R.id.loginProgressBar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //show "Create new account?"
    chooseRegister();
}//onConnected
```

I know calling the `client.disconnect()` during `onConnected` is untypical but the error happens before it.

EDIT 2: 
This is in fact in a fragment, and the client init is as follows:

```
googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .build();
```

where `getActivity()` is parent activity and `this` is the fragment. Does this have an effect? Should I make the parent activity the interface implementer and just redirect the calls to the fragment?

EDIT 3: Tried using the parent activity as the listener to the callbacks, it didn't help either.

EDIT:
Somebody will ask for it anyways even though it's pretty useless so: the error stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus.zzf(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqe.getAccountName(Unknown Source)
com.myfirm.myproject.LoginFragment.onConnected(LoginFragment.java:148)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzh(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlg.zznU(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlg.onConnected(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzpf(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzt(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzph(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: "LoginFragment.googleClient" may not be connected.. I'm not sure,,it's a guess..is there two googleClient?

Comment: Just one, just forgot the `LoginFragment.` when copying the line previously from elsewhere. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I met that error before, maybe this link will help you:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

And you must keep Google Client connect when using Google Plus API

Comment: I only use the API for that one call in `onConnected()` to verify the user's identity so I can just disconnect it after that. Can't really find anything useful there either :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it: the fragment is re-created for some reason so the googleClient gets re-created too and the new one isn't connected.

Logically this shouldn't affect the other fragment's client but it's a static variable. (doesn't actually need to be anymore, forgot to change)

Not sure yet but the fragment is probably re-created because the account chooser of the google client is a fragment. So for others with the same problem: multi-tiered fragments are the problem. They're often confusing.